# How to visualize a function to aid in optimization?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, mathematica

I am working on minimization of a function with more than two parameters. I want to see variations, local extremes, saddle points, etc. of this function to get some idea of how is this function in order to direct my studies.

What methods do you suggest? I've tried setting some variables especial values and plotting with respect to two remaining variables.

Comment: Can you post the function? Regards

Comment: I've calculated it numerically and as an analytic function it is so difficult to plot because it is yielded from simultaneously  minimization and maximization problem. For example, for the case of 4 variables I have a 4-D matrix for which each dimension represents one variable.

Comment: Greyscale/temperature 3D plot might help with this 4D example.

Comment: @Orangutango How can I use that in Matlab?

Comment: I've never done it before, but try [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/coloring-mesh-and-surface-plots.html).